# Moving from relational db to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a question on best practises or ideal way how I should store the data in the database. As an example I have a Site that has a Country assigned.

Table Countries: id|name|alpha2

Table Sites: id|countryId|name

Each Site has a reference to the country ID.

I would like to create a new website using Meteor and its mongodb and was wondering how I should store the objects. Do I create a colleciton "countries" and "sites" and use the country _id to as a reference? Then resolve the references using transform?

Looking at SimpleSchema I came up with the following:

```
Schemas.Country = new SimpleSchema ({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    alpha2: {
        type: String,
        max: 2
    }
});

Schemas.Site = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Site Name"
    },
    country: {
        type: Schemas.Country
    }
});

Countries = new Meteor.Collection("countries");
Countries.attachSchema(Schemas.Country);

Sites = new Meteor.Collection("sites");
Sites.attachSchema(Schemas.Site);
```

I was just wondering how this is then stored in the db. As I have 2 collections but inside the sites collection I do have defined country objects as well. What if a country changes its alpha2 code (very unlikely)?

Also this would continue where I have a collection called "conditions". Each condition will have a Site defined. I could now define the whole Site object into the condition object.  What if the Sitename changes? Would I need to manually change it in all condition objects?

This confuses me a bit. I am very thankful for all your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge with Meteor is that its tightly bound to Mongo, which is not good to built OLTP app that require normalized DB design. Mongo is good for OLAP kind of apps which fall in WORM  (Write Once Read Many) category. I would like to see Meteor supporting OrientDB as they do Mongo.

There can be two approaches:

1. Normalize the DB as we do in RDBMS and then retrieve data by hitting
   data multiple times. Here is a good article explaining this approach - [reactive joins in meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/).
   [Joins in
   Meteor](https://trello.com/c/BGvIwkEa/48-easy-joins-in-subscriptions)
   are suggested in future. You can also try Meteor packages - [publish
   composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) or
   [publish with
   relations](https://github.com/svasva/meteor-publish-with-relations)
2. Keep data de-normalized at least partially (for 1-N relation you can
   embed things in document, for N-N relation you may having separate
   collection). For instance, 'Student' can be embedded in 'Class' as
   student will never be in more than 1 class, but to relate 'Student'
   and 'Subject', they can be in different collections (N-N relation -
   student will have more than one subject and each subject will be
   taken by more than one student). For fetching N-N relation again you
   can use the same approach that is mentioned point above.

I am not able to give you exact code example, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I have looked into publish composite which looks quite promising. I will do a few tests with it. Probably I end up to mix between normalized and denormalized data. Especially with country where changes are unlikely. (Name and iso code). This could potentially just be denormalized I guess?